# Test if index value equals multiples of a certain number

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to come better way to test the index value for a  multiple of a certain value, lets say 10 in this case. The following is obviously not ideal. Looking for a better method. (Having mental block at the moment.)

```
$('.element').each(function(i){
   if (i==9 || i==19 || i == 29 || etc... ){
      alert('condition met');
   }
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r9x5jgx4/2/

Answer (score 3):

Use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_(.25))

```
$('#element').each(function(i){
   if (i % 9 == 0){
      alert('condition met');
   }
});
```

Note: The ID selector will select only one element, so I guess it is a typo in the question

---

Also you can look at the [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) if all the elements are siblings

```
$('.element:nth-child(9n)').each(function(i){
    alert('')
});
```

Working snippet:

```js
//just to populate
$('.element').html(function(i) {
  return i + 1;
});

//using index
$('.element').each(function(i) {
  if (i > 0 && i % 9 == 0) {
    $(this).css('color', 'red')
  }
});

$('.element:nth-child(9n)').each(function(i) {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'green')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
```

Comment: That actually doesn't do what I need. Your first suggestion would give me 10 elements the first time and then 9 thereafter. The 2nd suggestion also in not what I was looking for as I do not wish to select an individual element but do something on a specific index value.

Comment: @user357034 in that case `f ((i + 1) % 9 == 0) {` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r9x5jgx4/3/